# SQL Varchar convert to Date - Sybase

Tags: sql, date, sybase, varchar, sap-iq

I am using Sybase IQ and have the following stored as a varchar:

```
01October 2010
```

I want to convert this from varchar to date datatype with the following format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd   eg.2010-10-01
```

How would I write this SQL statement? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dates don't have a format, so the second point is irrelevant.

Comment: you've got a mismatch in your desired month format (mmm) and sample data (10); `mmm` is the 3-letter abbreviation for the month (eg, Oct), while you're showing that you want the 2-digit number (10); which is it that you want?  Regardless, see the convert(<datatype>,<expression>,<format-style>) function in the IQ Reference manual for details

Comment: I have updated the original question. I have read the documentation but struggling... Any ideas? I tried this:

SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR,visit_date,106) FROM tablename

but got this error: Data type conversion is not possible. CONVERT argument does not match the required data type.

Comment: @Siyual - Dates don't have a format?

Comment: @NickEdwards Dates don't have a "format" when they're stored in the database. They get formatted when you select them from the DB. The default formatting is yyyy-mm-dd, but you can convert them to a string (as you mentioned in your comment) with various formats (like your 106 example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With difficulty.  There's a reason you should never store dates and times as strings.

It's been awhile since I've used Sybase, but what we need to do is get the field into YYYY-MM-DD format, and then pass it to the DATE() or DATETIME() function.

Let's assume the first two characters are always the day of the month, and the last 4 characters are the year.  That means everything in between is the month.  Let's also assume that there are no leading or trailing spaces.  If either of these assumptions fails, then the query will fail.

Then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT DATE (
        RIGHT(UnnamedField,4) + '-' +
        CASE LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Unnamed,3,LEN(Unnamed) - 6)))
            WHEN 'January' THEN '01'
            WHEN 'February' THEN '02'
            WHEN 'March' THEN '03'
            .
            .
            .
            WHEN 'December' THEN '12'
        END + '-' + LEFT(UnnamedField,2)
    )
FROM UnnamedTable
```

Note that, as others have mentioned, the date data type is not a formatted datatype.  If possible you should format it in your application.  If you must do it in the query, use the CONVERT() function.

Comment: Thanks for sharing - I tried this and got NULLs... Any idea why?

Comment: @NickEdwards Try busting the expressions apart and seeing what you're getting.  Do `SELECT RIGHT(UnnamedField,4) AS Year, LEFT(UnnamedField,2) AS Day, ....` to see what each field is doing.  You're likely getting NULLs because one or more of the values is a null value.

Comment: @NickEdwards Also, I had `- 4` where I believe I needed `- 6`.  I've corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase is able to convert a string to a date. So if you use [`substring`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1601/doc/html/san1278453165210.html) to extract the date into a format that IQ can convert, then you can just use the `convert()` function.

Here's an example of how to do it:

Sample data:

```
create table #tmp1 (col1 varchar(100))
insert #tmp1 values ('01October 2010')
```

Query to convert the value to a date:

```
select 
    convert
    (
        date, 
        (
            substring(col1, 3, charindex(' ', col1) - 2) -- Month
            + substring(col1, 1, 2) -- Day
            + substring(col1, charindex(' ', col1), 5) -- Year (include the leading space)
        )
    ) 
from #tmp1
```

Now that the value is in a date format, you can use the [convert](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm) function to convert the date datatype to string, using your specified format. The default output for a date datatype is yyyy-mm-dd already.

---

**Edit:** After taking a look at @BaconBits' answer, I've realized that I could simplify the query a bit by using the substring function wrappers `left`, `right`, and the convert wrapper of `date`. It's the same logic; but using the simplified wrappers might make it easier to understand.

```
select 
    date
        (
            substring(col1, 3, charindex(' ', col1) - 2) -- Month
            + left(col1, 2) -- Day
            + ' ' + right(col1, 4) -- Year (include the leading space)
        )
from #tmp1
```

Comment: Thanks - i just copy and pasted the above and it doesn't return anything... Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: @NickEdwards It didn't give an error or anything? It just returned a column with a blank value? It's working fine for me when I test it. Are you using the test table I created, or did you modify it to work with your tables? If you're using my test table, can you do a `select * from #tmp1` to make sure there's a record inserted?